# Unwanted padding and margin in Bootstrap 3.3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.3 for a simple layout and the way I have it is:

For the body,html:

```
html,body{
    background: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

and then on each child section I have the following code:

```
.section-name{
    height:100%;
}
```

so that each section takes up 100% of the given device screen size. Now I don't know why but I have quite a big gap between each section, see the screen shots below:

[image: gap between section]

Notice the gap between the section, here's another screenshot:

[image: gap between section]

Now I went to the dev tool, in both Mozilla and Chrome, checked for any excessive padding or margin issues, but found none.

Then I checked if it was because of the white spaces in my html, took off the whitespaces and still that wasn't the issue.

I took off all the Bootstrap CDNs too, just to check if it was a Bootstrap issue and no it wasn't, even in the custom CSS I have written, the same issue persists.

I have even tried:

```
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Even that wouldn't take off the padding

### Edit

[Js fiddle depicting my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/gautamz07/7wfdee2d/)

Comment: You do realize the `.aboutus` section only has a height of 90%?

Comment: @connexo yup yup ! thats on intention :) , i am trying to re-create the problem , so there shouldbe a fiddle soon enuf , don't worry , thats not the problem .

Comment: If you find the html element that definitely has the unwanted padding (check in the inspector), try to add `padding: 0 !important;` to its style rules. sometime more than one rule affects the styling of an element, and the one which you gave padding: 0 might be less specific (in the sense of css specificity) than the rules adding a padding.

Comment: @connexo heres a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gautamz07/7wfdee2d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the solution you had a h2 inside your .section name that took margin-top of 20px,

Here the js fiddle

.section-title {`margin-top:0px;`}

http://jsfiddle.net/u2ttpkhg/1/

Comment: i am surprised that solved the problem , i had this problem in a couple of section, I'll check if thats the same issue and accept the answer if that is indeed the problem . One more question , how did u get to know the problem ??  via inspect element ? because i did the same and saw no excessive margin . was it a margin applied by the browser ?

Comment: When you use developers tools u have something as computed next to styles have a look at to it too, yes if there is any other problem do let me know, and the browser didn't apply it is already applied in bootstrapmin.css

Comment: ! thanks for the tip , btw , in my fiddle in am not using and neither are you bootstrap , have a look at the original fiddle i posted .

Comment: Okay it's says the user agent stylesheet meaning the browser stylesheet itself , in bootstrap h2 takes a margin top of 20px and margin bottom of 10px defined in bootstrapmin.css while the user agent stylesheet h2 takes a margin top and margin bottom of 20px

Comment: ! YES , anyways , but i still don't get it and sorry to be asking too many questions , but where did u see the useragent sheet saying the h2 took a margin-top of 20px ? computed styles ? because i looked both in computed styles and also in inspect element and none showed anything helpful .

Comment: Yes in developer tools itself you can scroll down in the styles itself you will find it

Comment: In Firebug, when you hover the element, you see the margin on the h2.

Comment: Yes with the help of mozilla extension firebug you can see it, in chrome with developer tools you can easily see the box properties in computed and in styles you can see what your properties and values defined in your stylesheet as well as user agent stylesheet

Comment: @sydonia , i have accepted your answer , though i have another question , but i guess this question of mine has been answered . so well , will go ask another question . Thanks a ton for your time .

Answer (score 1):

Is better if you could provide a fiddle, but here goes some things that I need to do sometimes:

Try to check above level elements too.

Also, you're using jumbotron? If so, it adds a top/bottom padding of 48px (via media query), take a look in that. Bootstrap has, by default, many classes which add unwanted paddings and margins.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , we'll will try and make a quick fiddle also , no , not using jumbotron and the issue seems to be more with just the custom css i have written , rather than bootstrap . anyways , as pointed out , will probably update my question with a fiddle .